# Building a Dynamic Treant Chart

Tags: javascript, json

Good morning all,

I've been working on a small project to build a dynamic treant.js tree chart. To achieve this i have based my code on the collapsable example using the JSON method.

Unfortunately the JSON within the script isnt exactly perfect JSON which is making my life particularly difficult.

I have written a piece of script which creates the required JSON as a string which when I write to the window and copy into the collapsable.js the chart is drawn perfectly.

An example can be seen here;

```
{chart: {container: "#collapsable-example",animateOnInit: true,node: {collapsable: true},animation: {nodeAnimation: "easeOutBounce",nodeSpeed: 700,connectorsAnimation: "bounce",connectorsSpeed: 700}},nodeStructure: { "id": 1, "parent": 0, "text": { "name": "Tony Obrien", "Title": "Managing Director" }, "children": [ { "id": 2, "parent": 1, "text": { "name": "Tony Obrien", "Title": "Managing Director" }, "children": [ { "id": 4, "parent": 2, "text": { "name": "Tony Obrien", "Title": "Managing Director" }, "children": [] } ] }, { "id": 3, "parent": 1, "text": { "name": "Tony Obrien", "Title": "Managing Director" }, "children": [ { "id": 5, "parent": 3, "text": { "name": "Tony Obrien", "Title": "Managing Director" }, "children": [] } ] }, { "id": 6, "parent": 1, "text": { "name": "Tony Obrien", "Title": "Managing Director" }, "children": [] }, { "id": 7, "parent": 1, "text": { "name": "Tony Obrien", "Title": "Managing Director" }, "children": [] } ] }
```

what im struggling with is after I've built that string converting it to an object that treant.js likes.

for example

```
var chart_config = {chart: {container: "#collapsable-example",animateOnInit: true,node: {collapsable: true},animation: {nodeAnimation: "easeOutBounce",nodeSpeed: 700,connectorsAnimation: "bounce",connectorsSpeed: 700}},nodeStructure: { "id": 1, "parent": 0, "text": { "name": "Tony Obrien", "Title": "Managing Director" }, "children": [ { "id": 2, "parent": 1, "text": { "name": "Tony Obrien", "Title": "Managing Director" }, "children": [ { "id": 4, "parent": 2, "text": { "name": "Tony Obrien", "Title": "Managing Director" }, "children": [] } ] }, { "id": 3, "parent": 1, "text": { "name": "Tony Obrien", "Title": "Managing Director" }, "children": [ { "id": 5, "parent": 3, "text": { "name": "Tony Obrien", "Title": "Managing Director" }, "children": [] } ] }, { "id": 6, "parent": 1, "text": { "name": "Tony Obrien", "Title": "Managing Director" }, "children": [] }, { "id": 7, "parent": 1, "text": { "name": "Tony Obrien", "Title": "Managing Director" }, "children": [] } ] }
```

When the JSON is copied and pasted from the result of the code that generated it works absolutley fine but.....

```
var tree =  eval({chart: {container: "#collapsable-example",animateOnInit: true,node: {collapsable: true},animation: {nodeAnimation: "easeOutBounce",nodeSpeed: 700,connectorsAnimation: "bounce",connectorsSpeed: 700}},nodeStructure: { "id": 1, "parent": 0, "text": { "name": "Tony Obrien", "Title": "Managing Director" }, "children": [ { "id": 2, "parent": 1, "text": { "name": "Tony Obrien", "Title": "Managing Director" }, "children": [ { "id": 4, "parent": 2, "text": { "name": "Tony Obrien", "Title": "Managing Director" }, "children": [] } ] }, { "id": 3, "parent": 1, "text": { "name": "Tony Obrien", "Title": "Managing Director" }, "children": [ { "id": 5, "parent": 3, "text": { "name": "Tony Obrien", "Title": "Managing Director" }, "children": [] } ] }, { "id": 6, "parent": 1, "text": { "name": "Tony Obrien", "Title": "Managing Director" }, "children": [] }, { "id": 7, "parent": 1, "text": { "name": "Tony Obrien", "Title": "Managing Director" }, "children": [] } ] })

chart_config = tree
```

This doesnt work. I get an unexpected token error. I have tried JSON.parse to no avail either. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your unexpected token error is likely from the `eval` call. Notice that it [takes a string representing js code as an argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval). You are giving it a js object, so the first '{' is likely the 'unexpected token'. Trying removing the `eval` wrapper and I bet it works.

Comment: As an added thing to note: in general `eval` is considered unsafe to use because it can introduce lots of security problems. If you want to convert JSON to and from a string you can use `JSON.stringifiy` and `JSON.parse`